# Can we create a retargeting list in AdWords based on email open data in Marketo?

Tags: google-ads-api, email, marketo

Based on people who interact with an email campaign through marketo I would to create a retargetting campaign in Adwords.

Is it even possible using RTP?

Comment: If you can put a pixel on the mail, yes, you can create a remarketing list with that list and there will be people.

Comment: I never thought of that we can a pixel on the mail. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What kind of interactions you'd like to capture?

If it's clicks so you can pass the leads through some page that will send events to GA and eventually redirect them to the desired page.

if you're interested to capture opens it's more complicated, you will need to capture GA's client ID for each one of your leads when they fill out a form.

There are lead data onboarding tools that might help with this challenge.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I use Marketo RTP to achieve this. Will update the post if I succeed.